# C# Trying to find an unbound binding source

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I couldn't think of a better title. But basically I have multiple combo box controls and I want each one to have the same list of values (which in my case are objects that I have in a List) to select from but I want each combo box to store a separate value.  If I use a binding source, and prepare it by looping thru my list and adding all possible values, and then tie that to all the combo boxes, of course, all combo boxes change to the same value when you change one.  The other alternatives are either:

1. To have a separate binding source for each combo box
2. To avoid binding sources and loop thru my list and add to each combo box

Both alternatives sound sloppy and too repetitive in code.  I'm aware that binding sources are traditionally used to share values between multiple controls, but I'm only looking to share the "source".  Is there a way to do this cleanly?

Comment: [Bind multiple ComboBox to a single List - Issue: When I choose an item, all combo boxes change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35864906/3110834)

Comment: Thank you, it was difficult to find the right keywords to use to search for similar posts...I am flagging my post as duplicate