# Two ComboBox with same DataSource causes Selection to be forgotten

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, bindingsource

I have `BindingSource` defined:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bsContractors;
this.bsContractors.DataSource = typeof(Contractor);
```

and then a `ComboBox` with a `DataSource` defined like so:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmbConstructionContractors1;
this.cmbConstructionContractors1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.bsProject, "Id", true));
this.cmbContractors1.DataSource = this.bsContractors;
this.cmbContractors1.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.cmbContractors1.ValueMember = "Id";
this.cmbContractors1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbContractor1Selected);
```

This works fine.
I have another `ComboBox` defined on another `Form` using the same DataSource:

```
this.cmbContractorName2.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", myView.bsProject, "Id", true));
this.cmbContractorName2.DataSource = projectView.bsContractors;
this.cmbContractorName2.ValueMember = "Id";
this.cmbContractorName2.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.cmbContractorName2.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbContractor2Selected);
```

When this 2nd `ComboBox` is displayed, the first `ComboBox`, which has something selected, gets reset to the first entry, which is blank.
If I pull down on the first `ComboBox`, the list is still there, it just 'forgot' which one was selected.

Edit: I've discovered that when displaying the 2nd `ComboBox`, the EventHandler of the 1st `ComboBox1` somehow gets assigned to `cmbContractors2Selected` instead of the original `cmbContractors1Selected`

Comment: to make them independent each combobox needs it __own__ bindingsource!

Comment: You can read about the reason and possible solutions here: [Bind multiple ComboBox to a single List - Issue: When I choose an item, all combo boxes change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35865838/3110834)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving it its own binding object:

```
this.cmbContractorName2.DataSource = new BindingSource(projectView.bsContractors, null);
```

This will separate the currency managers.