# Winform (.Net) databind and selection problem

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

It was a looooooong time since I did a winform desktop application in .Net and I wanted to do some selections based on listboxes. The problem is that any item I select in a listbox also changes the selection of the other listboxes bound to the same data. I tried to find people who have had the same problem but couldn't find any so I guess I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Anyone have any hints? See below for the basic code.

**Class for handling data** (to which I later use as DataSource in listboxes).

```c#
public class Registry
{
    public ICollection<Data.Vertice> Vertices { get; set; } = new List<Data.Vertice>();
}
```

**How I set the data source to a listbox**

```c#
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = _registry.Vertices;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Title";
```

Comment: When you move `Current`, all Controls bound to the same source of data are synchronized. Isn't that expected? What do you want to happen instead? That Controls other than the one you're currently interacting with lose synchronization and show something else? What else? -- You can always suspend their binding, but...

Comment: If you want the same source of values, but different selections you need for each list box it's own BindingSource. All BindingSources can use the same list but each will manage it's own selected item.

Comment: So using the same DataSource also creates some common sync of selected item between all the listboxes?

Comment: This is already answered here for ComboBox: [Bind multiple ComboBox to a single List - Issue: When I select an item, all combo boxes change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35865838/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

[Reza Aghai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei) Solved the problem by finding a a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35865838/3110834) which I had missed in my search.

Basically a single [BindingManagerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingmanagerbase?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) is created and reused if you use the same DataSource. This can be solved by creating a new DataSource by for example doing the following:

```c#
DataSource = yourList.ToList()
```